# How to invoke a method after attaching to a remote JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

for testing/debugging purposes I need to invoke some service methods from my debugger (built-in intellij idea debugger) with my custom parameters, this method may be a member of a class instance or a static function, is this possible? how?

I can set a break point and change the parameters value when the method is about to be executed but I do not want to do this

Comment: Well I think you need to put a break point to somewhere in any case to be able to get a thread. It doesn't have to be the exact same method you want to execute but you should be able to access to the instance or service or whatever somehow, so that you can run your method on that. It may be as easy as creating an instance via constructor or using some instance from some dependency context.

Comment: You can do this using the evaluator. When a breakpoint is hit, simply click the icon that kinda looks lika a caluculator located besides the step over, step into, etc. buttons.

Comment: I am already doing exactly this, but because the process to cause the method to be invoked is too long (I mean in the UI layer of the application) it is very time-consuming. my ideal solution could be an environment that I can get a reference to my desired object (for example a Spring Context) in the JVM and call its method. of course, I can implement something like this with reflection and expose its API (through HTTP for example) but I do not want to reinvent the wheel. I need something like `Jshell` for attaching a remote running JVM.